# XML Mass Changing Type Hexadecimal

Tags: c#, xml

So I have 80 000 lines of XML. They follow this general structure:

```
   <Object type="0xa14" id="Steel Dagger">
  <Class>Equipment</Class>
  <Item/>
  <Texture>
     <File>lofiObj5</File>
     <Index>0x60</Index>
  </Texture>
  <SlotType>2</SlotType>
  <Tier>0</Tier>
  <Description>{equip.A_sharp_dagger_made_of_steel.}</Description>
  <RateOfFire>1</RateOfFire>
  <Sound>weapon/blunt_dagger</Sound>
  <Projectile>
     <ObjectId>Blade</ObjectId>
     <Speed>140</Speed>
     <MinDamage>20</MinDamage>
     <MaxDamage>60</MaxDamage>
     <LifetimeMS>400</LifetimeMS>
  </Projectile>
  <BagType>1</BagType>
  <OldSound>daggerSwing</OldSound>
  <feedPower>5</feedPower>
  <DisplayId>{equip.Steel_Dagger}</DisplayId>
```

But what I want to do is change all the types of the XML.

The type is this part:

```
type="0xa14"
```

I want them to start from the beginning (first XML) with 0x00 then increase by 1 in hexadecimal until it reaches the end.

Here is the pure pastebin of the XML file: 
[XML Github File](https://github.com/InfernapeRotMG/Ghoul-Swagger-Of-Doom-Master/blob/master/db/data/dat1.xml)

Comment: "0xa14" has 3 hex characters, "0x00" has 2, please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            int index = 0;
            foreach(XElement obj in doc.Descendants("Object"))
            {
                obj.SetAttributeValue("type", "0x" + index++.ToString("x"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDocument and update all `type` attributes in the loop

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"pathToFile");
var index = 1;
foreach (var ground in document.Descendants("Ground"))
{
    ground.Attribute("type").Value = index.ToString("X"); 
    // 'X' convert integer to hexadecimal representation
    index++;
}

document.Save(@"pathToUpdatedFile");
```